# special characters in a modrwrite rule, possible?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't get it.

this rule works

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/index.html$ index.phpXXpage=$1 [L]
```

this rule don't work

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/index.html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Ok, the problem is the questionmark. But why does this rule not working?

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/index.html$ index.php\?page=$1 [L]
```

How can i use a questionmark in a modrwewrte rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your regex has character class that is including hyphen twice. This rule should for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/index\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: You URL is ending with `.jpg` extension but your rules were all ending with `.html` so obviously `.jpg` URL won't be rewritten :) I suggest you better describe your requirement clearly in the question.

Comment: this is a screenshot for you ;)

Comment: ok please provide as much info as you can. Just `Did not work` with a URL doesn't describe anything. I checked screenshot though and say that 2nd rules was applied and it became `index.php`. Since we didn't use `R` flag therefore query string wasn't shown in your test output. If you want URL to change in browser also you should use: `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/index\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA,R]`

Comment: Sorry, my english is very bad (that is maybe the reason why i am writing only short sentences :)

I dont want a redirect, i want to show (for example) this url http://domain.com/keyword/index.html in the browser, but the server should use this url http://domain.com/index.php?s=keyword

Comment: Never test using that site, its not reliable. I am providing you full code that you should place in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` and test on your on server.

Comment: Edited the code, I have tested this code and it is working on my server.

Comment: Hi anubhava, your code works but if i remove the R (i dont want a redirect) the code did not work. Buty Why? Strange ...

Comment: I didn't suggest `R` flag in my answer. Do you have any CMS or PHP framework installed which is conflicting without `R` flag.

Comment: Right, i think wordpress ist the problem.